# How to automatically refresh MongoDB database without using requests?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express

I want to be able to refresh the MongoDB database without using user requests - the reason being that the database requests and API calls must be maintainable and not exceed any limits. I am using Node, express, vue and Mongo. What is the doable concept for this?

Basically, I can update the database manually by using secret post requests to the server for example but is there any way to do this automatically once per month? One ugly method could be to use for loop and set a timeout for automatic server calls.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by `refresh the MongoDB`? What exactly do you want to achieve

Comment: I mean updating the data in the MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

This could be something to work with, inside for loop just have to fetch new data and update MongoDB database. Whole process is initialized with a post request to a specific url.

```
const port = 3000,
express = require("express"),
app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.send(`This is the page for serverUpdateTest`);
});


app.post("/initServerUpdate", (reg, res) => {
  for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++) {

      setTimeout(()=>{console.log('updating..')}, i * 1000); //update server here
  };
})


app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```